# Removing Space or spaces in the starting of the specific element and consecutive space in between text using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want remove consecutive spaces to single space and after opening or before closing of particular element space or spaces need to be removed with out effecting sub elements.

Input:

```
<products>
<product1> Product P  <i>Product</i> Q</product1>
<product1> </product1>
<product2>  Product <b>Q Product R</b>   </product2>
<product2><b></b></product2>
<product3>Product  R  </product3>
<product4> Product S </product4>
<product5>Product T </product5>
</products>
```

XSLT Tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
</xsl:transform>
```

Output:

```
<products>
   <product1>Product P<i>Product</i>Q
   </product1>
   <product2>Product<b>Q Product R</b></product2>
   <product3>Product R</product3>
   <product4>Product S</product4>
   <product5>Product T</product5>
</products>
```

Required Output:

```
<products>
<product1>Product P <i>Product</i> Q</product1>
<product2>Product <b>Q Product R</b></product2>
<product3>Product R</product3>
<product4>Product S</product4>
<product5>Product T</product5>
</products>
```

Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rules are not clear to me, for instance in `<product2>  Product <b>Q Product R</b>   </product2>` there is whitespace between `<b>Q Product R</b>   </product2>`, why is that completely eliminated and not collapsed to a single space?

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen, Please see the required output in that after opening an element and before closing an element no need of space without effecting sub elements spacing and consecutive space between the text or elements need to be removed

Comment: By repeating the same vague description I won't understand your requirements better.

Comment: That white space was eliminated since that space is before closing of an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the rules are clear from one example but

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="products/*/text()[not(following-sibling::node()[self::*]) and not(preceding-sibling::node()[self::*])]">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="products/*/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[self::*]]">
      <xsl:value-of select=". => replace('\s+$', '') => replace('\s+', ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="products/*/text()[following-sibling::node()[self::*]]">
      <xsl:value-of select=". => replace('^\s+', '') => replace('\s+', ' ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

comes closer to your desired result so perhaps you can adapt it to your needs if they are clear.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMoc

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, Its partially working in xslt2.0 version i am getting Ambiguous warning and "<product1>Product P <i>Product</i>Q</product1>" after "<i>" element closing space was deleted